# VideoView restarting when keyboard event occurs

Tags: java, android, animation, android-videoview

I have a login screen which has an animated background.

However, I've noticed a problem where when I click on my input fields and the keyboard pops up, the animation restarts itself and this is really jarring.

I've tried modifying the `android:configchanges` in the Manifest by adding `"orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` and that has had no effect.

I've also tried to override the VideoView methods, as you can see in my code.

From what I understand the activity gets destroyed when the keyboard pops up and this results in the restart, but I can't see the fix and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

[MainActivity.Java](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1827649)

[activity_main.xml](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1827650)

Comment: try this in proper way android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: Still results in the same problem

Comment: setOnPreparedListener and MediaPlayer  object remove and try

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code,

public class MTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private VideoView videoviews;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mtest);
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI(){
        try{
            videoviews = findViewById(R.id.videoviews);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.introducation);

            videoviews.setVideoURI(uri);

            videoviews.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    videoviews.start();
                }
            });

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MTag ="onResume";
        Log.v(Tag,MTag);
        videoviews.start();
    }}
```